# Drupal 7 Extend footer to bottom of brower for short page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In Drupal 7, for short page without too much content, the footer can move up and leave some blank space below the footer.
How to extend the footer to JUST the bottom for short page situation?
Might need JavaScript (jQuery) to dynamically get the browser height, content height.... then dynamically set zone-footer-wrapper.... to exactly the bottom of browser?

Answer (score 0):

This can very easily be done with CSS (and a little HTML rejiggering).

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}
```

Where `.wrapper` is you main content container, `.push` is an empty div and the last child of `.wrapper`, and `.footer` is a div and the next sibling of `.wrapper`.